# CASE, WHEN, THEN on UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I have this issue where if there is no record in `copy_on_write.id` then the `UPDATE listings SET images = (SELECT images FROM new_vals)` runs and wipes out `listings.images` with nothing.

So, I am trying to use a condition to only run the `UPDATE listings` if `copy_on_write.images` exist.

right now I get:

```
psql:queries/copy-to-source.sh:20: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 10:       CASE WHEN images <>
```

---

```
WITH
  new_vals AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM copy_on_write
    WHERE copy_on_write.posted_by = 102550922::text
      AND copy_on_write.id = 4
  ),

  updates AS (
    SELECT images FROM new_vals,
      CASE WHEN images <> ''
        THEN UPDATE listings SET images = (SELECT images FROM new_vals)
      END
  )
SELECT internal_id FROM new_vals
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `updates` CTE like this:

```
...
updates AS (
    UPDATE listings SET 
    images = new_vals.images
    FROM new_vals
    WHERE new_vals.images <> ''
)
....
```

Note, that:

- Your `new_vals` CTE  should always return maximum one record, otherwise this won't works correct.
- Also this not updates `listings` table, if  `new_vals` returns images column, but it is empty string (or null). If in such cases you need run update anyway, then remove `WHERE new_vals.images <> ''` at all.
- And also, this statement will update all `listings.images` records. Do you really want this?